# autoscroller in android view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am completely new to Android, my first attempt is to use a LinearLayout to position several controls, but my emulator screen is not that large to contain all my controls and the output doesn't display all of them and there is no vertical scroller automatically added.
What should I do to make them all viewable ?

```
<LinearLayout>
<control_1/>
<control_2/>
///////...
<control_n/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your layout in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).  Your code would look like:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- put your controls in here -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```